# Which tools I could use for launching an instance in openstack with python script

Tags: python, openstack

Basically, I need to write a python script which takes arguments with argparser and launches instance of VM in openstack, optionally creates a disk tool and mounts it to VM.
I've tried to search for similiar scripts and found [this](https://gist.github.com/desurus/df98910ece5f52085d58) , generally this should work out, but it is quite old and when I looked for PythonSDK documentation on openstack website and found many different clients and python api for that clients, which I should use?

Comment: I haven't written a python-tool by myself to interact with the openstack-api, but I can tell you, that you should use the `openstacksdk`: https://github.com/openstack/openstacksdk In the repository there are also examples of how to use it. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each OpenStack service has its own python client library, such as [python-novaclient](https://pypi.org/project/python-novaclient/), [python-cinderclient](https://pypi.org/project/python-cinderclient/), [python-glanceclient](https://pypi.org/project/python-glanceclient/). They also provide user guides, e.g. [How to use cinderclient](https://docs.openstack.org/python-cinderclient/latest/), have a look and you will find out the answer.

Generally, I prefer trying command-line in terminal first, like `cinder create --display-name corey-volume 10` or `nova boot --image xxx --block-device source=volume,id=xxx corey-vm`, to verify the command exists and the idea works, then change it to python code. If I don't know how to use it or get unexpected errors in the script, I will go to [Github](https://github.com/openstack/python-novaclient/tree/master/novaclient/v2) to check its source code, it really helps, especially in debugging.